# Type-safe function taking a partial object and inferring the values of the object in return type (like Object.freeze)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Hi Typescript wizards,

I need some guidance on a TypeScript challenge I'm facing.

Essentially, I'm trying to create a function that has the same return type as Object.freeze, but with added intellisense and type safety for the object passed as a parameter. The aim is to have the inferred type for the group variable in the example code block below be `{ id: "1" }` and not `{ id: string }`, while also ensuring that the keys and values are properly type-checked.

```
interface Group{
    id: string;
}

const myFunction = (group: Partial<Group>) => group;

const group = myFunction({id: "1"})
// ^ typeof group = {id: "1"} and not {id:"string"}
```

Using `Object.freeze`, the return type is good, but I don't have any type-safety and intellisense for the object passed as parameter.

```
const group = Object.freeze({id: "1"})
// ^ typeof group = {id: "1"} which is what I want
```

Do you know if it's possible to achieve this in TypeScript?

Combining `Object.freeze` and `Partial` doesn't give the good return type:

```
const myFunction = (group: Partial<Group>) => Object.freeze(group)

const group = myFunction({id: "1"})
// ^ typeof group = {id: string} but I have intellisense
```

Comment: ① Please [edit] to make `Group` an `interface` instead of a `class` since you're not initializing its property and not using the constructor in the question; it'll be much cleaner not to bring up the issue at all. ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Navy2m) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hello, I edited it but I was using a class because in my code, Group is a class defining a TypeOrm entity. But you're right, for the example, an interface is fine.

You're approach seems to work only with Typescript > 5. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Yes, it was introduced in TS5.0. If you have some dependency on an older version of TypeScript you should [edit] the question to specify acceptable version ranges (but be advised that such dependencies will tend to be increasingly difficult to support as the language has been evolving fairly rapidly).  How do you want to proceed here?

Comment: Hi again @jcalz.

@wonderflame gives me a solution that suits my needs, so I accepted it. He also added the `const T` solution for TS>=5.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typescript version >= 5.0**

In Typescript 5.0 the [const type parameters](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#const-type-parameters) were added to the language. With their use it can be really straightforward:

```
const myFunction = <const T extends Partial<Group>>(group: T) => group;
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYeGrW)

**Typescript version < 5.0**

Unfortunately, there is no straightforward way of doing this with older versions.
The way you should define your function is similar to how  `Object.freeze`' makes the type constant. The overload that is used in your case is:

```
freeze<T extends {[idx: string]: U | null | undefined | object}, U extends string | bigint | number | boolean | symbol>(o: T): Readonly<T>;
```

The interesting part is that even though we are using two generic parameters(`T`, `U`) we are only passing `T` to the `freeze`. It is because we are using `U` inside of the `T`'s definition, which lets the Typescript infer the type correctly.

```
const myFunction = <
  T extends Partial<{ [K in keyof Group]: U[K] }>,
  U extends Group,
>(
  group: T,
): Readonly<T> => group;
```

The reason why we need `U` is also to help TS to understand the exact values of the `T`'s properties.

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrQOow)

If you want to have support for the inheritance and expect some sub class that extends the base class we will have to rewrite the function as following:

```
class BaseEntity {
  id: string;
}

class Group extends BaseEntity {
  phone: number;
}

type EntityConstructor<E extends BaseEntity> = new (...args: [any]) => E;

const _myFunction2 =
  <ExtendedEntity extends BaseEntity>(
    _entity: EntityConstructor<ExtendedEntity>,
  ) =>
  <T extends Partial<{ [K in keyof U]: U[K] }>, U extends ExtendedEntity>(
    group: T,
  ): Readonly<T> =>
    group;

const group3 = _myFunction2(Group)({ id: '1', phone: 12 });
```

Note that the even if we adapt the types `_myFunction2(Group, {})` won't work

The reason why passing `(Group, {})` doesn't work is because, at that moment, the typescript doesn't know exactly what the type of `ExtendedEntity` is. Thus, it can be anything extending `BaseEntity`. However, in the variant that I propose, we define `T` and `U` only after the `ExtendedEntity` Is precisely defined to be `Group`

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoYp9N)

Comment: Hi !

First of all, thanks for your answer.

It seems to be a good start, but I lose some type-safety.

For example, in my previous example, with your solution, this is working:
```
myFunction({id: 1})
```
whereas it should show a type error for the id.

Comment: Can you check [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N73MGN)? It is typesafe, but unfortunately, it doesn't autosuggest you the properties when you invoke `myFunction`

Comment: Actually, ignore the previous comment. This [approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrQOow) works as expected. Let me know if it works for you so I can update the answer

Comment: I think it works perfectly !

And I was just playing with the code to try to understand how it works (and I'm still not sure to understand how it works ), and I figured out that the part `& keyof U` seems to be useless. Can you confirm ?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right; it wasn't useless in the approach described in the comment, which I said you should ignore. Thanks for noting. Updating the answer

Comment: There is a last issue I'm facing.
I tried to update the code to make it more generic. But the inferred type is not the good one. In the following playground, it infers only the values for the keys coming from `BaseEntity`. Any idea how to solve this ?
[playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8XM9w)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WoYp9N) solves that issue?

Comment: Yes, I think it can work in my case.
Could you explain why we need to use this approach ? I mean why we can't have this type as generic and avoid this first function passing the type down ?

Comment: Btw, the approach proposed by @jcalz solves totally my problem, but it uses const type parameters which are introduced in TS5.0.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to advise you to use the `const T` as well, but I thought that there is a high chance that you are using `ts < 5`. The reason why passing `(Group, {})` doesn't work is because at that moment typescript doesn't know exactly what will be the type of `ExtendedEntity`. Thus, it can be anything extending `BaseEntity`. However in the variant that I propose we define `T` and `U` only after the `ExtendedEntity` Is exactly defined to be `Group`

Comment: It's perfectly clear, thanks a lot for given me the solution and the explanations ;)

I will go with your version first, and keep in mind that I will be able to use `const T` as soon as we migrate to TS5.

I think it could be nice to give both TS < 5 and TS >= 5 solutions in the answer.

Comment: will update the answer now

Comment: Perfect. I accepted your answer :)

Thanks again for your help !